# How can I re-create a child component in React

Tags: reactjs

In my React component, it renders a child component.  React instantiants an object of ChildComponent when it renders.

My question is how can I force react to reinstantiants an object of when I click a button in Parent Component? I want the ChildComponent to be 'reset', i.e. like when it is newly called the constructor.

export class ParentComponent extends React.Component {

```
private handleButtonClick() {
// re-instantiate ChildComponent

}
  public render() {
    return (
<Button onClick={handleButtonClick}/>
<ChildComponent />
) 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to re-render, just update some state. If you want to call the constructor of children, then update some state and pass it as key={someState}.

```
state = {
   someState: true
}

private handleButtonClick() {
   // just update someState
   this.setState((oldState) => ({someState: !oldState.someState}))
}
public render() {
    return (
        <>
          <Button onClick={handleButtonClick}/>
          <ChildComponent key={String(someState)} />
        </>
    ) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hook or state variable and add as a property of ChildComponent.
And in the handleButtonClick callback function, you need to change the value of the variable and your ChildComponent will be re-render